# Returning a user object in json after after consuming the login api that uses basic authentication

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I'm quite new in Web API, so I have a Web API controller that has to return a user object in json so that I can use that json data in my xamarin forms client. I have a validite method that reads or gets data from the database then I call that validate method on BasicAuthenticationAttribute  OnAuthorization method which uses Generic Identity and Generic Principal which I don't fully understand how they work. I need to pass my user object which is returned in the validate method of which I'm puzzled I need help here is what I did:

```
  //This method is used to check the user credentials
    public static bool Login(string username, string password)
    {
        string hashedPassword = Util.HashPassword(password);
        IEmployee  obj = new EmployeeBL();


        var userData = obj.GetByUserName(username);

        return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userData.UserName) && 
    string.CompareOrdinal(userData.Pass, hashedPassword) == 0);

    }
```

The code below is in my BasicAuthenticationAttribute class OnAuthorization method of which I dont want to use GenericIdentity since it only takes name I want to pass my user object which I can't figure out since I'm new :

```
            if (UserValidate.Login(username, password))
            {
                var identity = new GenericIdentity(username);
                IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
                if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
```

Then here is my API Controller which I need to return a json object:

```
     [BasicAuthentication]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetEmployee()
    {
        //string username = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;

        var response = Request.CreateResponse<string> 
         (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created, "Success!");
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways:

1. let web api serialize it for you:

   var jObject = JObject.Parse("success!");
   return jObject;
2. var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   response.Content = new StringContent(jObject.ToString(),Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
   return response;

Comment: if you go with option 1, the return type is JObject